# mpi cannot access process rank

Tags: process, mpi

I just installed mpi and it doesnt really seems to work properly. Below I wrote a very simple implementation of this library:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int my_rank;
    int size;
    int namelen;
    char proc_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(proc_name, &namelen);

    if (my_rank == 2)
        printf("Hello – I am process 2\n"); 
    else
        printf("Hello from process %d of  %d on %s\n", my_rank, size, proc_name);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Compiled and executed with:

```
mpicc -o example example.c
mpirun -np 4 ./example
```

The output on CLI is:

```
Hello from process 0 of  1 on manos-pc
Hello from process 0 of  1 on manos-pc
Hello from process 0 of  1 on manos-pc
Hello from process 0 of  1 on manos-pc
```

It seems that it can't access other processes.
I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: There is something wrong with your MPI installation. Hence you must provide details about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had other implementation of MPI installed so there was a confict in the output.Problem solved by removing OpenMPI